# Running Celery as daemon won't use redis broker

Tags: redis, celery, daemon, broker

I have

```
celery==3.1.23
Django==1.9.1
redis==2.10.5
ii  redis-server       2:2.8.19-3     amd64          Persistent key-value database with networ
ii  redis-tools        2:2.8.19-3     amd64          Persistent key-value database with networ
```

My configuration settings have the lines

```
# Celery
BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'
BROKER_TRANSPORT = 'redis'
# start worker with '$ celery -A intro worker -l debug'
```

and my configuration file celery.py (standard practice is to name it this way, but confusing in my opinion) is

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import django

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'intro.settings')
django.setup()

app = Celery('intro')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

The config /etc/default/celeryd (also confusing naming) is

```
# copy this file to /etc/default/celeryd
CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"
VIRTUAL_ENV_PATH="/srv/intro/bin"

# JRT
CELERY_BIN="${VIRTUAL_ENV_PATH}/celery"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/srv/intro/intro"

# Python interpreter from environment.
ENV_PYTHON="$VIRTUAL_ENV_PATH/python"

# How to call "manage.py celeryd_multi"
CELERYD_MULTI="$ENV_PYTHON $CELERYD_CHDIR/manage.py celeryd_multi"

# How to call "manage.py celeryctl"
CELERYCTL="$ENV_PYTHON $CELERYD_CHDIR/manage.py celeryctl"

# Extra arguments to celeryd NOTE --beat is vital, otherwise scheduler
# will not run
CELERYD_OPTS="--concurrency=1 --beat"

# %n will be replaced with the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
CELERYD_USER="jimmy"
CELERYD_GROUP="jimmy"

# Name of the projects settings module.
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="intro.settings"

#CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'
#export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="settings"

#CELERYD_MULTI="/home/webapps/.virtualenvs/crowdstaff/bin/django-admin.py celeryd_detach"
```

My /etc/init.d/celeryd file is

```
#!/bin/sh -e
VERSION=10.1
echo "celery init v${VERSION}."
if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error: This program can only be used by the root user."
    echo "       Unprivileged users must use the 'celery multi' utility, "
    echo "       or 'celery worker --detach'."
    exit 1
fi


# Can be a runlevel symlink (e.g. S02celeryd)
if [ -L "$0" ]; then
    SCRIPT_FILE=$(readlink "$0")
else
    SCRIPT_FILE="$0"
fi
SCRIPT_NAME="$(basename "$SCRIPT_FILE")"

DEFAULT_USER="celery"
DEFAULT_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
DEFAULT_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n.log"
DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
DEFAULT_NODES="celery"
DEFAULT_CELERYD="-m celery worker --detach"

CELERY_DEFAULTS=${CELERY_DEFAULTS:-"/etc/default/${SCRIPT_NAME}"}

# Make sure executable configuration script is owned by root
_config_sanity() {
    local path="$1"
    local owner=$(ls -ld "$path" | awk '{print $3}')
    local iwgrp=$(ls -ld "$path" | cut -b 6)
    local iwoth=$(ls -ld "$path" | cut -b 9)

    if [ "$(id -u $owner)" != "0" ]; then
        echo "Error: Config script '$path' must be owned by root!"
        echo
        echo "Resolution:"
        echo "Review the file carefully and make sure it has not been "
        echo "modified with mailicious intent.  When sure the "
        echo "script is safe to execute with superuser privileges "
        echo "you can change ownership of the script:"
        echo "    $ sudo chown root '$path'"
        exit 1
    fi

    if [ "$iwoth" != "-" ]; then  # S_IWOTH
        echo "Error: Config script '$path' cannot be writable by others!"
        echo
        echo "Resolution:"
        echo "Review the file carefully and make sure it has not been "
        echo "modified with malicious intent.  When sure the "
        echo "script is safe to execute with superuser privileges "
        echo "you can change the scripts permissions:"
        echo "    $ sudo chmod 640 '$path'"
        exit 1
    fi
    if [ "$iwgrp" != "-" ]; then  # S_IWGRP
        echo "Error: Config script '$path' cannot be writable by group!"
        echo
        echo "Resolution:"
        echo "Review the file carefully and make sure it has not been "
        echo "modified with malicious intent.  When sure the "
        echo "script is safe to execute with superuser privileges "
        echo "you can change the scripts permissions:"
        echo "    $ sudo chmod 640 '$path'"
        exit 1
    fi
}

if [ -f "$CELERY_DEFAULTS" ]; then
    _config_sanity "$CELERY_DEFAULTS"
    echo "Using config script: $CELERY_DEFAULTS"
    . "$CELERY_DEFAULTS"
fi

# Sets --app argument for CELERY_BIN
CELERY_APP_ARG=""
if [ ! -z "$CELERY_APP" ]; then
    CELERY_APP_ARG="--app=$CELERY_APP"
fi

CELERYD_USER=${CELERYD_USER:-$DEFAULT_USER}

# Set CELERY_CREATE_DIRS to always create log/pid dirs.
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=${CELERY_CREATE_DIRS:-0}
CELERY_CREATE_RUNDIR=$CELERY_CREATE_DIRS
CELERY_CREATE_LOGDIR=$CELERY_CREATE_DIRS
if [ -z "$CELERYD_PID_FILE" ]; then
    CELERYD_PID_FILE="$DEFAULT_PID_FILE"
    CELERY_CREATE_RUNDIR=1
fi
if [ -z "$CELERYD_LOG_FILE" ]; then
    CELERYD_LOG_FILE="$DEFAULT_LOG_FILE"
    CELERY_CREATE_LOGDIR=1
fi

CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL:-${CELERYD_LOGLEVEL:-$DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL}}
CELERY_BIN=${CELERY_BIN:-"celery"}
CELERYD_MULTI=${CELERYD_MULTI:-"$CELERY_BIN multi"}
CELERYD_NODES=${CELERYD_NODES:-$DEFAULT_NODES}

export CELERY_LOADER

if [ -n "$2" ]; then
    CELERYD_OPTS="$CELERYD_OPTS $2"
fi

CELERYD_LOG_DIR=`dirname $CELERYD_LOG_FILE`
CELERYD_PID_DIR=`dirname $CELERYD_PID_FILE`

# Extra start-stop-daemon options, like user/group.
if [ -n "$CELERYD_CHDIR" ]; then
    DAEMON_OPTS="$DAEMON_OPTS --workdir=$CELERYD_CHDIR"
fi


check_dev_null() {
    if [ ! -c /dev/null ]; then
        echo "/dev/null is not a character device!"
        exit 75  # EX_TEMPFAIL
    fi
}


maybe_die() {
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Exiting: $* (errno $?)"
        exit 77  # EX_NOPERM
    fi
}

create_default_dir() {
    if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
        echo "- Creating default directory: '$1'"
        mkdir -p "$1"
        maybe_die "Couldn't create directory $1"
        echo "- Changing permissions of '$1' to 02755"
        chmod 02755 "$1"
        maybe_die "Couldn't change permissions for $1"
        if [ -n "$CELERYD_USER" ]; then
            echo "- Changing owner of '$1' to '$CELERYD_USER'"
            chown "$CELERYD_USER" "$1"
            maybe_die "Couldn't change owner of $1"
        fi
        if [ -n "$CELERYD_GROUP" ]; then
            echo "- Changing group of '$1' to '$CELERYD_GROUP'"
            chgrp "$CELERYD_GROUP" "$1"
            maybe_die "Couldn't change group of $1"
        fi
    fi
}


check_paths() {
    if [ $CELERY_CREATE_LOGDIR -eq 1 ]; then
        create_default_dir "$CELERYD_LOG_DIR"
    fi
    if [ $CELERY_CREATE_RUNDIR -eq 1 ]; then
        create_default_dir "$CELERYD_PID_DIR"
    fi
}

create_paths() {
    create_default_dir "$CELERYD_LOG_DIR"
    create_default_dir "$CELERYD_PID_DIR"
}

export PATH="${PATH:+$PATH:}/usr/sbin:/sbin"


_get_pidfiles () {
    # note: multi < 3.1.14 output to stderr, not stdout, hence the redirect.
    ${CELERYD_MULTI} expand "${CELERYD_PID_FILE}" ${CELERYD_NODES} 2>&1
}


_get_pids() {
    found_pids=0
    my_exitcode=0

    for pidfile in $(_get_pidfiles); do
        local pid=`cat "$pidfile"`
        local cleaned_pid=`echo "$pid" | sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g'`
        if [ -z "$pid" ] || [ "$cleaned_pid" != "$pid" ]; then
            echo "bad pid file ($pidfile)"
            one_failed=true
            my_exitcode=1
        else
            found_pids=1
            echo "$pid"
        fi

    if [ $found_pids -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "${SCRIPT_NAME}: All nodes down"
        exit $my_exitcode
    fi
    done
}


_chuid () {
    su "$CELERYD_USER" -c "$CELERYD_MULTI $*"
}


start_workers () {
    if [ ! -z "$CELERYD_ULIMIT" ]; then
        ulimit $CELERYD_ULIMIT
    fi
    _chuid $* start $CELERYD_NODES $DAEMON_OPTS     \
                 --pidfile="$CELERYD_PID_FILE"      \
                 --logfile="$CELERYD_LOG_FILE"      \
                 --loglevel="$CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL"    \
                 $CELERY_APP_ARG                    \
                 $CELERYD_OPTS
}


dryrun () {
    (C_FAKEFORK=1 start_workers --verbose)
}


stop_workers () {
    _chuid stopwait $CELERYD_NODES --pidfile="$CELERYD_PID_FILE"
}


restart_workers () {
    _chuid restart $CELERYD_NODES $DAEMON_OPTS      \
                   --pidfile="$CELERYD_PID_FILE"    \
                   --logfile="$CELERYD_LOG_FILE"    \
                   --loglevel="$CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL"  \
                   $CELERY_APP_ARG                  \
                   $CELERYD_OPTS
}


kill_workers() {
    _chuid kill $CELERYD_NODES --pidfile="$CELERYD_PID_FILE"
}


restart_workers_graceful () {
    echo "WARNING: Use with caution in production"
    echo "The workers will attempt to restart, but they may not be able to."
    local worker_pids=
    worker_pids=`_get_pids`
    [ "$one_failed" ] && exit 1

    for worker_pid in $worker_pids; do
        local failed=
        kill -HUP $worker_pid 2> /dev/null || failed=true
        if [ "$failed" ]; then
            echo "${SCRIPT_NAME} worker (pid $worker_pid) could not be restarted"
            one_failed=true
        else
            echo "${SCRIPT_NAME} worker (pid $worker_pid) received SIGHUP"
        fi
    done

    [ "$one_failed" ] && exit 1 || exit 0
}


check_status () {
    my_exitcode=0
    found_pids=0

    local one_failed=
    for pidfile in $(_get_pidfiles); do
        if [ ! -r $pidfile ]; then
            echo "${SCRIPT_NAME} down: no pidfiles found"
            one_failed=true
            break
        fi

        local node=`basename "$pidfile" .pid`
        local pid=`cat "$pidfile"`
        local cleaned_pid=`echo "$pid" | sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g'`
        if [ -z "$pid" ] || [ "$cleaned_pid" != "$pid" ]; then
            echo "bad pid file ($pidfile)"
            one_failed=true
        else
            local failed=
            kill -0 $pid 2> /dev/null || failed=true
            if [ "$failed" ]; then
                echo "${SCRIPT_NAME} (node $node) (pid $pid) is down, but pidfile exists!"
                one_failed=true
            else
                echo "${SCRIPT_NAME} (node $node) (pid $pid) is up..."
            fi
        fi
    done

    [ "$one_failed" ] && exit 1 || exit 0
}


case "$1" in
    start)
        check_dev_null
        check_paths
        start_workers
    ;;

    stop)
        check_dev_null
        check_paths
        stop_workers
    ;;

    reload|force-reload)
        echo "Use restart"
    ;;

    status)
        check_status
    ;;

    restart)
        check_dev_null
        check_paths
        restart_workers
    ;;

    graceful)
        check_dev_null
        restart_workers_graceful
    ;;

    kill)
        check_dev_null
        kill_workers
    ;;

    dryrun)
        check_dev_null
        dryrun
    ;;

    try-restart)
        check_dev_null
        check_paths
        restart_workers
    ;;

    create-paths)
        check_dev_null
        create_paths
    ;;

    check-paths)
        check_dev_null
        check_paths
    ;;

    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/${SCRIPT_NAME} {start|stop|restart|graceful|kill|dryrun|create-paths}"
        exit 64  # EX_USAGE
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Which is old, very long, and seems to contain nothing I can change to effect the broker used except the location of the default values script `CELERY_DEFAULTS=/etc/default/celeryd` (confusing name again). I admit I pretty well copied and pasted this script without a full understanding though I do know how init.d scripts work.

When I run `/etc/init.d/celeryd start` The workers start up, but ignore the BROKER django settings pointing to my redis server, and try to read RabbitMQ instead. The log file /var/log/celery/w1.log

```
[2016-11-30 23:44:51,873: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
```

So celery is trying to use RabbitMQ, not Redis. There are other posts  that complain of the same problem on Stack overflow, but none are resolved (as far as I can tell). I put djcelery in installed apps, as it seemed to make `celeryd_multi` management command available, but I don't want to use celery beat, and the documentation says this is no longer necessary. I have my own queue set up to run management commands, and I have had too many problems with setting up celerybeat in the past.

I have got the thing working by running `sudo -u jimmy /srv/intro/bin/celery -A intro worker &` and this works and uses the correct Redis queue (does anyone know why is it called a broker?), but wont restart on server power cycle, does not write to the log files, and I just don't feel this is a clean way to run celery workers.

I don't really want to use /etc/init.d scripts as this is the old way of doing things, and running as upstart has come and gone to replace this, and now systemd is the supported way of doing this (please correct me if I am wrong). There is no mention of these methods on the official documentation
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.0.0/userguide/daemonizing.html#init-script-celeryd
which makes me think that celery is no longer being supported, and perhaps there is a better maintained way of doing this. It is a wonder it has not been built into the core.

I did find this
https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/3.1/extra/supervisord/supervisord.conf
but there is no mention of broker in the config files, and I doubt that this will help me using Redis.

How do I get Celery running as a daemon to start automatically on reboot, and use Redis as a message queue, or is my only way of using Celery for asynchronous running of functions in Django to use the RabbitMQ message queue?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure celery loads the correct broker, add broker parameter to Celery class.

```
app = Celery('intro', broker=settings.BROKER_URL)
```

Reference:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#application

Comment: I did try this, but it made no difference. I will try it again and if it works mark you ranswer as correct.

Comment: You can use supervisor to restart the celery on start up, try google 'celery supervisor'. Or you can hard code the line as 
app = Celery('intro', broker='redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0') to force it point to redis. Must be the settings are not loaded.

Comment: I had no success with the broker setting when using the init.d script in the celery documentation. init.d scripts are outdated anyway. Using supervisord though works well, and will stop and restart better than issuing a kill -9 for the workers. Thanks +1